# Compare 2 df.columns with multiple conditions have wrong result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column df.a. which have values of 1, 0, -1, and compare to a new column df.c. The requirement is as follows:

1. The count(df.c) must be between -1 and 1.
2. If the df.a is greater than the previous df.c by 1 or less than the previous df.c by -1, the previous df.c will be put into the current df.c.
3. Otherwise, if df.a is equal to zero. it will also put the previous df.c to current df.c.
4. If df.a equal to  1 or -1, it will calculate df.a with previous df.c and put into current df.c

My coding is as follows:

Initialize `df.c` as `df['a'][0] == 1`.

```
a=df['a'] + df['count'].shift(1) < -1 
b=df['a'] + df['count'].shift(1) > 1

c=df['count'].shift(1) == -1
d=df['count'].shift(1) == 1
e=df['count'].shift(1) == '0'

g=df['a']=='-1'
h=df['a']=='1'
i=df['a']=='0'

conditions=[a|b|i&d|i&c,h&e|g&e,e&i|c&h|d&g]
choices=[df['count'].shift(1), df['a'], '0']
df['count'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df['count'])
```

**My question is** when I compare `df['a'][4]`, `df['count'][6]` should be (-1, '1') but the result is 1, it should fall into (e) -1 + 1 = 0. Any suggestion? Have I done something wrong?

```
    a   c   expected result

0   1   nan 1
1   1   1.0 1
2   0   1.0 1
3   1   1.0 1
4   -1  0   0 
5   0   1.0 0
6   1   1.0 1
7   1   1.0 1
8   -1  0   0
9   -1  0   -1
10  -1  0   -1
11  0   1.0 -1
12  -1  0   -1
13  1   1.0 0
14  0   1.0 0
15  1   1.0 1
```

Comment: What is the count column here (same as c?)?

Comment: This looks like a recursive computation where the value of a row is dependent on the computed value of the previous row, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want to compare the current df.a with previous df.c to find out the current df.c.

Comment: BTW, my question should be when I compare df['a'][12] and df['c'][11], the answer should be 0 in df['c'][12]. But it shows  -1.